# How can I use the indexOf() function to find an object with a certain property

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I have an object, Pet, and one of the functions is to retrieve its name.

```
public class pet{
    private String petName;
    private int petAge;

    public pet(String name, int age){
        petName = name;
        petAge = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return petName;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return petAge;
    }

}
```

I then have an ArrayList which holds a collection of pets as shown in the code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

pet Dog = new pet("Orio", 2);
pet Cat = new pet("Kathy", 4);
pet Lion = new pet("Usumba", 6);

ArrayList<pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
pets.add(Dog);
pets.add(Cat);
pets.add(Lion;
```

I was wondering how I could retrieve the index in the ArrayList or the object that has the name I need. So if I  wanted to find out how old Usumba was, how would I do this?

Note: This is not my actual piece of code, it's just used so that I can better explain my problem.

#### Edit 1

So far, I have the following but I was wondering if there was a better or more efficient way

```
public int getPetAge(String petName){
    int petAge= 0;

    for (pet currentPet : pets) {
        if (currentPet.getName() == petName){
            petAge = currentPet.getAge();
            break;
        }
    }

    return petAge;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `indexOf()` for this purpose, unless you abuse the purpose of the `equals()` method.

Use a `for` loop over an `int` variable that iterates from `0` to the length of the List.

Inside the loop, compare the name if the ith element, and if it's equal to you search term, you've found it.

Something like this:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
    if (pets.get(i).getName().equals(searchName)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

// index now holds the found index, or -1 if not found
```

If you just want to find the object, you don't need the index:

```
pet found = null;
for (pet p : pets) {
    if (p.getName().equals(searchName)) {
        found = p;
        break;
    }
}

// found is now something or null if not found
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Note that you can't use `==` to properly compare Strings. Always use `.equals()`. Also, see alternative impl.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already stated, you cannot use indexOf() for this directly. It would be possible in certain situations (lambdas, rewriting hashCode/equals etc), but that is usually a bad idea because it would abuse another concept.

Here's a few examples of how we can do that in modern Java:
(as the index topic has already been answered quite well, this only handles direct Object return)

```
package stackoverflow.filterstuff;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class FilterStuff {


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Pet dog = new Pet("Orio", 2); // again, naming conventions: variable names start with lowercase letters
        final Pet cat = new Pet("Kathy", 4);
        final Pet lion = new Pet("Usumba", 6);

        final ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
        pets.add(dog);
        pets.add(cat);
        pets.add(lion);

        try {
            simpleOldLoop(pets);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try {
            simpleLoopWithLambda(pets);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try {
            filterStreams(pets);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try {
            filterStreamsWithLambda(pets);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }



    private static void simpleOldLoop(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets) {
        System.out.println("\nFilterStuff.simpleOldLoop()");
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Kathy': " + filterPet_simpleOldLoop(pPets, "Kathy"));
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Hans': " + filterPet_simpleOldLoop(pPets, "Hans"));
    }

    private static Pet filterPet_simpleOldLoop(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets, final String pName) {
        if (pPets == null) return null;
        for (final Pet pet : pPets) {
            if (pet == null) continue;

            if (Objects.equals(pet.getName(), pName)) return pet;
        }
        return null;
    }



    private static void simpleLoopWithLambda(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets) {
        System.out.println("\nFilterStuff.simpleLoopWithLambda()");
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Kathy': " + filterPet_simpleLoopWithLambda(pPets, (pet) -> Boolean.valueOf(Objects.equals(pet.getName(), "Kathy"))));
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Hans': " + filterPet_simpleLoopWithLambda(pPets, (pet) -> Boolean.valueOf(Objects.equals(pet.getName(), "Hans"))));
    }
    private static Pet filterPet_simpleLoopWithLambda(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets, final Function<Pet, Boolean> pLambda) {
        if (pPets == null) return null;
        for (final Pet pet : pPets) {
            if (pet == null) continue;

            final Boolean result = pLambda.apply(pet);
            if (result == Boolean.TRUE) return pet;
        }
        return null;
    }



    private static void filterStreams(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets) {
        System.out.println("\nFilterStuff.filterStreams()");
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Kathy': " + filterPet_filterStreams(pPets, "Kathy"));
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Hans': " + filterPet_filterStreams(pPets, "Hans"));
    }

    private static Pet filterPet_filterStreams(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets, final String pName) {
        return pPets.stream().filter(p -> Objects.equals(p.getName(), pName)).findAny().get();
    }



    private static void filterStreamsWithLambda(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets) {
        System.out.println("\nFilterStuff.filterStreamsWithLambda()");

        System.out.println("Pet named 'Kathy': " + filterPet_filterStreams(pPets, p -> Objects.equals(p.getName(), "Kathy")));

        final Predicate<Pet> pdctHans = p -> Objects.equals(p.getName(), "Hans"); // we can also have 'lambda expressions' stored in variables
        System.out.println("Pet named 'Hans': " + filterPet_filterStreams(pPets, pdctHans));
    }

    private static Pet filterPet_filterStreams(final ArrayList<Pet> pPets, final Predicate<Pet> pLambdaPredicate) {
        return pPets.stream().filter(pLambdaPredicate).findAny().get();
    }



}
```

Along with your Pet class, extended by toString():

```
package stackoverflow.filterstuff;

public class Pet { // please stick to naming conventions: classes start with uppercase letters!
    private final String    petName;
    private final int       petAge;

    public Pet(final String name, final int age) {
        petName = name;
        petAge = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return petAge;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Pet [Name=" + petName + ", Age=" + petAge + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't understand some of the functions so I'm going over the documentation right now. They look pretty advanced but very useful. Appreciate it!